# Alternativa às variáveis de sessão em classe fora do MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

Sou iniciante no MVC e estou construindo uma aplicação que não possui camada de dados, mas preciso estruturar muitas classes de backend e não acho legal sujar a Controller.

Pra isto, criei uma pasta apartada do MVC onde coloquei minha lógica.
Essa lógica é chamada dentro da Controller e utiliza minhas Models.

Só que nessa pasta, por não ser Model, nem View e nem Controller, não reconhece variáve de sessão, nem TempData, nem ViewBag e nem ViewData.

Existe outra alternativa para eu conseguir persistir os dados?

Essa classe apartada possui 8 métodos chamado por 1 método principal e eu preciso transitar e persistir umas variáveis entre eles.

Segue código com as variáveis de sessão (q não funcionam):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//using SystemTools.Areas.Vida.Models;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using SystemTools.Areas.Vida.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using SystemTools.Services;

namespace SystemTools.Services
{
    public class ProcessarValidacao
    {
        Session["premioTotalCoberturas"] = "0";
        Session["premioTotal"] = "0";
        public Validacoes val;
        public Utils util;


        public List<ValidaIAProposta03> d03;
        public List<ValidaIAProposta04> d04;

        public List<ValidaIATrailler> d09;
        public List<ValidadorIA> listGroup;
        public ValidadorIA reg;

        #region Processamento
        public List<ValidadorIA> ProcessamentoValidacao(List<string> lines, string prestamista)
        {
            (...)

            for (int i = 0; i < qtLines; i++)
            {
                (...)

                switch (tipo)
            {
                case "3":
                    d03 = ValidaProposta03(lines[i], d03);

                    (...)
                        break;

                case "4":
                    d04 = ValidaProposta04(lines[i], d04, formaCobranca, prestamista);
                    (...)
                        break;

                case "9":
                    d09 = ValidaProposta09(lines[i], d09, formaCobranca, prestamista);
                    (...)
                        


                        break;
            }
        }  
            return listGroup;

        }

    public List<ValidaIAProposta03> ValidaProposta03(string line, List<ValidaIAProposta03> d03, int sequencialGarantias)
    {
        (...)
            
            
            if (validarPremio.Trim() != "")
        {
            if (!val.IsNumero(validarPremio))
            {
                //!!!!!!!!!!!!TRATAR
                int somaPremio = int.Parse(Session["premioTotalCoberturas"].ToString()) + int.Parse(validarPremio);
                Session["premioTotalCoberturas"] = somaPremio.ToString();
            }


        }
        else
        {

            validarPremio = "ERRO" + " <br/> Campo Obrigatório em branco"; erroNaLinha = true;
        }
       (...)

            return d03;
    }
    #endregion

    public List<ValidaIAProposta04> ValidaProposta04(string line, List<ValidaIAProposta04> d04)
    {
        (...)
            

            if (validarpremiototal.Trim() != "")
        {
            if (!val.IsNumero(validarpremiototal))
            {
                //
            }
            else if (int.Parse(validarpremiototal) != int.Parse(Session["premioTotalCoberturas"].ToString()))
            {
                validarpremiototal = "ERRO - Prêmio Esperado: " + Session["premioTotalCoberturas"].ToString() + " <br/>" + validarpremiototal; erroNaLinha = true;
            }
            else
            {
                int premioTotal = int.Parse(Session["premioTotal"].ToString()) + int.Parse(validarpremiototal);
                Session["premioTotal"] = premioTotal.ToString();
            }

        }

       (...)

            return d04;
    }



    public List<ValidaIATrailler> ValidaProposta09(string line, List<ValidaIATrailler> d09, int totalPropostas, int totalRegistros)
    {
        (...)
           

            if (validartotaldepremios.Trim() != "")
        {
            if (!val.IsNumero(validartotaldepremios))
            {
                validartotaldepremios = "ERRO" + " <br/>" + validartotaldepremios;
                erroNaLinha = true;
            }
            else if (int.Parse(validartotaldepremios) != int.Parse(Session["premioTotal"].ToString()))
            {
                validartotaldepremios = "ERRO - Prêmio esperado: " + Session["premioTotal"].ToString() + " <br/>" + validartotaldepremios; erroNaLinha = true;
            }
        }

        (...)

            return d09;
    }

      }
     }
```

Comment: se entendi bem, tem uma *class library* e que tratar nela coisas como Session mas sem ter Session é isso? de qualquer forma, existe um endpoint/controller que recebe a requisição antes de passar para essa classe certo? não pode fazer lá?  dê mais detalhes pq isso não ficou claro

Comment: de qualquer forma, pode usar um outro repositório qualquer, como Redis ou MongoDB, ou ainda algum package de memorycache se for o caso

Comment: Mais ou menos.
A class connversa com a controller através do método 'ProcessamentoValidacao'.
Nese método eu tenho referências a outros 8 métodos.
Eu preciso ficar entrando e saindo dos métodos e persistir alguns dados de um método para o outro. No WebForms eu havia feito isso com variável de sessão.
Só depois de tudo consumado, eu volto com meu resultado para o 'ProcessamentoValidacao' pra ele conversar com a Controller (nesse ponto não preciso mais da sessão).

Comment: [Imagem ilustrativa](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1naFR9NN7RnGf2FeM4KeNfsbsYVNL41Y46aYCZBnRTNM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: ah ok, mas nesse caso então a controller ao chamar o método `ProcessamentoValidacao` deveria passar para a camada de serviço todos os dados necessários para ela fazer a validação. Poderia por exemplo criar uma classe `ValidacaoContexto` e passar nela "lines" e "prestamista" os demais dados que estariam na Session ou qq outra class que exista só no nivel da controller, assim desacopla as camadas e não precisa de dependencias com objetos que só devem existir na camada da controller em outras camadas :)